# Special Waveform Generation

Tags: waveform

I am wondering if I need any special kind of waveform / function generator in order to generate a signal with the following description / parameters:
19 V max and 6mA operational limits;
unbalanced biphasic waveform;
delivers triplets of pulses at 5 ms intervals every 20 ms;
adjustable pulse-width (0.4-0.6 µs).

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: biphasic? or bipolar output? no adjustments besides PW50?

Comment: rise time?> adjustable amplitude?  may draw it and indicate tolerance

Comment: Rather than try to find something, if it is just generating pulses it might be easiest just to build one using a high-speed PIC32 or ARM microcontroller with a fast cycle time (5 - 10 ns).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could breadboard this out of some basic gates. One possibility: an oscillator giving the 200 Hz (5 ms) basic pace. Divide by four using a cascade of two J-K flip-flops (= a two-bit binary counter). Use an AND or NOR gate to detect a 00 or 11 binary on the output of the counter, and use that detection result to gate the 5ms signal (you may end up with short residual glitches, not sure. Would require a tiny further post-processing step). This should result in 3 pulses (edges) spaced 5 ms and a fourth pulse missing. Next, use that to trigger a single-shot with an RC cell for your variable timing constant, and use a potentiometer to tweak the pulse width.

[200 Hz clock] -> [1:4 divider with 00 detection] -> [00 gate] -> [single-shot]

Bi-phase means what? Two outputs like that? What shift between them? A tandem potentiometer might be used to tweak the pulse width in both channels.

And oh you'd need a discrete transistor circuit to level-shift this to 19 V.
An op-amp could do it for slower signals, but sub-microsecond rail-to-rail pulses are probably too much to ask from a typical op-amp that can stand 19+V Vcc.